# Uploadifive within Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, file, user-interface, upload, dialog

I've been scratching my head for ages over this now.  I'm using uploadifive on a page to allow for file uploading, this is working fine.  Now, when I put the browse button/queue within a jQuery UI dialog the file browser won't open when the 'browse' button is clicked.

In the code below I've wrapped the uploadifive script in a function and then tried calling that function when the dialog box opens and it still doesn't work????  The 'browse' button appears as it should but just doesn't do anything when it's clicked.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks,

```
    // File upload wrapped in function
    function upbind(){
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
            'auto'             : true,
            //'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
            'formData'         : {
                                   'timestamp' : '1234567890',
                                   'token'     : '1234567890'
                                 },
            'queueID'          : 'queue',
            'uploadScript'     : 'uploadify/uploadifive.php',
            'queueSizeLimit'   : 1,
            'multi'            : false,
            'buttonText'       : 'BROWSE',
            //'removeCompleted'  : true,
            'onSelect'         : function(file) {
                                    $(".uploadifive-button").css("display", "none");
                                },
            'onCancel'         : function() {
                                    $(".uploadifive-button").css("display", "inherit");
                                },                  
            'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); alert('The file ' + data + ' uploaded successfully.');}

        });
    }

    // Call upbind script
    upbind();

    // Process dialog box
    $("#dialog-add-product").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        open: function(){
            $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(2)').focus();
            upbind();
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function(){
                // Function here

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                // Function here

                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    }); // End add product dialog
```

The dialog HTML is here;

```
<div id="dialog-add-product" class="dialog_add" title="Add product">
<form name="formAddProduct" id="formAddProduct" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="" id="addcat" />
<table>
      <tr>
        <td height="10" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText" width="120"></td>
        <td height="10" align="left" valign="middle"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Product title:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-ptitle" type="text" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus" id="fields-ptitle" tabindex="5" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Category:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><label for="fields-pcategory"></label>
          <select name="fields-pcategory" id="fields-pcategory" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus">
                            <option value="19">Door parts</option>
                            <option value="1">Hinges</option>
                            <option value="21">Testing 222</option>
                        </select></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Product code:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-pcode" type="text" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus" id="fields-pcode" tabindex="5" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Quantity:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-pqty" type="text" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus" id="fields-pqty" tabindex="5" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Trade price (£):</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-pprice" type="text" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus" id="fields-pprice" tabindex="5" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Clearance price (£):</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-pclearance" type="text" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus" id="fields-pclearance" tabindex="5" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Unit:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-punit" type="text" class="inputBoxAdd editstatus" id="fields-punit" tabindex="5" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Description:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><textarea name="fields-pdescription" id="fields-pdescription" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Image:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle"><div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText">Active:</td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="fields-pactive" type="checkbox" id="fields-pactive" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle" class="smallText"><div class="savetick"><img src="images/accept.png" width="24" height="24" /></div><div class="savespinner"><img src="images/savespin.gif" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
        <td height="31" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any error on debugger tool?

Comment: can you upload HTML code here?

Comment: I've add the dialog HTML to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there is a problem with the `modal: true` option, it prevents the windows file, then set to `modal: false` and its work.

```
// Process dialog box
$("#dialog-add-product").dialog({
    ...
    modal: false,
    open: function(){
        $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(2)').focus();
        upbind();
    },
    ...
}); // End add product dialog
```

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with `modal` option. It works if modal is false for me. But `modal:true` can be able to upload in firefox but doesnt work in chrome

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put your `div` inside the form tag and give a try.

Even i had the same problem.

Check the solution given by [geek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5860768/1551730)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations.

I couldn't get your code to work with `.uploadifive({`. I had to replace it with `.uploadify({` that [I found on the demo page](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/). That change at least got the code to run correctly in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Secondly, I'd give you code another review because with the default uploadify code, the browser appears to work just fine.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/t6hHr/2/